# Footer is at the bottom of one html page but in the middle of another

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a footer at the bottom of the page for each HTML page.

On my main index page, it sets at the bottom because I have several sections on the page, which includes a block of text and a video sitting side by side above the footer.

On another HTML page I just have my navigation bar and the footer styled. The main tag has no content. The footer on this page is half way up the screen.

I've looked through different solutions and have tried bottom: 0 as well as position: fixed and position: absolute, but absolute just causes the footer on my main page to cover up the horizontal line between the text/video section and the footer, and the very bottom part of the video and text. Fixed causes it to sit over all the content and at the bottom of the page does the same as absolute.

```
.about {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    float: left;
    height: 50vh;
    margin-top: 3em;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.videos {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50vh;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3em;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}

.frontPageVideo {
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    height: 20vh;
    margin-top: 5em;
}
```

How can I set the footer at the bottom of every page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your body a `min-height: 100vh` css rule to ensure your page is never shorter than the viewport.

You might also consider using flex to establish the header/main/footer layout.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.main > * {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: bisque;
}

.main header,
.main footer {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div>Content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by Ray Hatfield, I would also add it to the `html` element. Here is what I always include in my websites:

```css
html, body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I had all of that but the width and adding that actually helped with rest of the page too. Thank you!